# How to make divs floating next to one another?

Tags: html, css, css-float

Aim : I want to make my divs floating next to one another like this.

http://jsfiddle.net/x8Abc/1/

```
.post {
   float:left;
   padding:10px;
   margin:5px;
   border:1px solid #000;
   width:25%;
}
```

Problem : when I have a content which of of more length in an in between div, then it is pushing the div below it to side like this.

http://jsfiddle.net/W3afJ/

```
.post {
   float:left;
   padding:10px;
   margin:5px;
   border:1px solid #000;
   width:25%;
}
```

How can I achieve a uniform well packed layout like jsfiddle.net/x8Abc/1/ ?

Comment: Fiddle links require code in your question.

Comment: @isherwood : Its too much code to paste

Comment: What do you want, give the div's a fixed height? Scroll stuff? Or if you want them to have variable height's, where should the next one be positioned?

Comment: You don't have to paste it all. Just the relevant bits.

Comment: @DennisHunink : when the screen width is low, i need each div to be place below and next to the previous and top one. Currently when one div is having a lot of content, its pushing the div under it to right side.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `display: inline-block` in this situation.

Amend your css like so:

```
.post {
   display: -moz-inline-stack;
   display: inline-block;
   *display: inline;
   padding: 10px;
   margin: 5px;
   border: 1px solid #000;
   width: 25%;
   zoom: 1;
}
```

[Here's a fiddle as well](http://jsfiddle.net/zWReG/)

To align the blocks vertically change the `vertical-align` css property, e.g.

```
.post {
   display: -moz-inline-stack;
   display: inline-block;
   *display: inline;
   padding: 10px;
   margin: 5px;
   border: 1px solid #000;
   width: 25%;
   zoom: 1;
   vertical-align: top;
}
```

For more information on making `display: inline-block` work in IE (as I have done above) see here:

https://blog.mozilla.org/webdev/2009/02/20/cross-browser-inline-block/

Comment: This works very well in recent versions of FF, Chrome, Opera, IE9 and Safari/Win.  Nicely done and presented.

Comment: @MarcAudet it should also work in IE7/8 too (all bases covered here)

Comment: no problem :) Mozzila's docs are often useful, if you've not stumbled across is before I'd recommend looking at their Developer Network: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/

Answer (score 2):

You have a few different options:

1. Give each of your posts a fixed height, and set the overflow property to `auto`. This will (obviously) ensure that each is the same height and so avoid the issue where one floats next to its sibling, but will add scrollbars to `div`s with a lot of text, and blank space to the bottom of those with little (see it [here](http://jsfiddle.net/cherryflavourpez/H3mAw/)):

   ```
   .post {
       float: left;
       padding:10px;
       margin:5px;
       border:1px solid #000;
       width:25%;
       height: 250px;
       overflow: auto;
    }
   ```
2. Stick with `float` to lay out your posts, and ensure that the first post in each row is cleared ([see it in action](http://jsfiddle.net/cherryflavourpez/qWxpq/)) . That can be achieved like this*:

   ```
   .post:nth-child(3n + 1) { clear:both; }
   ```
3. Change your approach to laying out your posts to use `inline-block`, like this:

   ```
   .post {
       display: inline-block;
       padding:10px;
       margin:5px;
       border:1px solid #000;
       width:25%;
    }
   ```

There is a fork of your original example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/cherryflavourpez/r2RFJ/). I would recommend going with this approach, as it gives you the ability to vertically-align your posts as you see fit, and won't restrict the amount of copy in each like option 1. [This article](http://blog.mozilla.org/webdev/2009/02/20/cross-browser-inline-block/) is a good read, and details how to get it working even in older browsers.

* Note that IE<9 won't support the `nth-child` pseudo-class, so you'd need a JavaScript fallback for those browsers.

Comment: thanks for the answer. I followed the inline method pointed by Sean